# Why setTimeuot console.log every second?

Tags: javascript

Why setTimeout function does console.log every second and not increasing count?

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
     ((a) => {
          setTimeout(function() {
               console.log( a );
          }, a * 1000);
     })( i );
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, please clarify it

Comment: Because you start five different timers at the same moment, with timeouts of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 seconds.

Comment: I think they mean "why doesn't the length between timeouts increase?" The issue is that they do

Comment: Well, epxplain what your are exactly trying to accomplish

Comment: If you just want to log increasing number every seconds, then you can use this: `let count = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(count);
  count++;
}, 1000);`

Comment: If you want the events to happen in a sequence, you need to start the next one inside of the triggering event handler. With this code, they are counting their times in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

The first time through your loop `i = 1` which means that `i * 1000` will cause your first timer to be called after 1 second. Then you call the immediately invoked funtion a second time since your loop continues which causes you to create a SECOND timer at which point in your loop `i = 2`. Therefore, `i * 1000` will be `2000` millisecond. This will happen likewise for `i` being equal to 3 and 4. So your `console.log` will be called as follows:

1. `console.log` called at 1 second (1000 milliseconds) with first timer
2. `console.log` called at 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds) with second timer
3. `console.log` called at 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds) with third timer
4. `console.log` called at 4 seconds (4000 milliseconds) with fourth timer